# how to use JSON responce in a url

Tags: android, json, web-services

i am developing an android application with RESTful WebServices

suppose ,
 i am sending a url http request as

somewebservice/data/access

and is sends data as {"serviceMessageCode":1,"serviceMessageText":"aaaaaa","items":null}

and i want to send another request with  that obtained key as

somewebService/rest/services/secure/getcategories?apikey=aaaaaa

```
    int sMC = jsonObj.getInt("serviceMessageCode");

            if (sMC == 1) {
                smt = jsonObj.getString("serviceMessageText");
```

can i use

somewebService/rest/services/secure/getcategories?apikey=smt

i think i should not do so , some one tell me how to achieve this..!!

please help....

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you could not pass some data by GET parameters. It really depends on Rest API on your backend server. Do you use any REST client or base apache http package classes to make requests to server?

Edited:

```
BufferedReader in = null;

try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    String uri = String.format("http://somewebService/rest/services/secure/getcategories?apikey=%s", Config.API_KEY); // API_KEY is constant value written somewhere or could you pass it as method argument
    URI website = new URI(uri);
    request.setURI(website);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    String line = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while(null != (line = in.readLine())) {
        builder.append(line);
    }

    in.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}
```

Comment: am using apache http packages